# python regular exp. with a unicode char

Tags: python, regex

I need a reg exp that will parse something like-

```
"2 * 240pin"
```

where the * can be either the regular star or unicode char \u00d7 or just an x. This is what I have but its not working:

```
multiple= r'^(\d+)\s?x|*|\\u00d7\s?(\d+)(\w{2,4})$'
multiplepat= re.compile(multiple, re.I)
print multiplepat.search(u'1 X 240pin').groups()
```

returns

```
multiplepat= re.compile(multiple, re.I)
File "C:\Python26\lib\re.py", line 188, in compile
return _compile(pattern, flags)
File "C:\Python26\lib\re.py", line 243, in _compile
raise error, v # invalid expression
error: nothing to repeat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `*` as it is a quantifier in the context you use it. But you could also use a character class. So try this:

```
ur'^(\d+)\s?[x*\u00d7]\s?(\d+)(\w{2,4})$'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
multiple= r'^(\d+)\s[xX\*\\u00d7]\s?(\d+)(\w{2,4})$'
```

Comment: You don’t need to escape the `*` inside a character class.

Comment: oh, that's right, i forgot - but it does not harm to escape it :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use [character sets (`[]`)](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) :

> []
>
> Used to indicate a set of characters. Characters can be listed individually, or a range of characters can be indicated by giving two characters and separating them by a '-'. **Special characters are not active inside sets**.

```
>>> m= u'^(\\d+)\\s?[x*\u00d7]\\s?(\\d+)(\\w{2,4})$'
>>> mpat=re.compile(m)
>>> mpat.search(u'1 * 240pin').groups()
(u'1', u'240', u'pin')
>>>
```